# Ionic 3 toFixed() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I know this is just a basic and simple question I tried to searching for it but can't find one related answer.

So what happened is I am trying to get the 20% of the total **scrollHeight** and - minus to the **total scroll height**

Here is my code below.

I have a condition likes this `if ((ev.target.offsetHeight + ev.target.scrollTop) >= (ev.target.scrollHeight - (parseFloat(ev.target.scrolllHeight).toFixed(2) * 0.2)))
// do something inside the condition`

It sais that **toFixed** is not a function because of the [ts] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

I tried this `parseFloat((ev.target.scrolllHeight: number)).toFixed(2)` but has no luck.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing in `parseFloat(ev.target.scrolllHeight)` is an error as `scrollHeight` is already a `number`.  `parseFloat` takes a string.

## Fix

`ev.target.scrolllHeight.toFixed(2)` should not be an error.

Comment: Didn't try that out in the first place. Thanks!